# Word file corrupted after accidentally saving as RTF format

Tags: microsoft-word

As I said in the title: Word file corrupted after accidentally saving as RTF format and the actual content of the file turn to the squares:

[image: screenshot]

I want get back to actual content, how can I do that?  I've used some online and offline tools to repair the RTF but none of them worked.

Comment: if you saved the file as rtf then shouldn't the original doc/docx file be still there?

Comment: I just found the .asd file but after opening it gives me same result as above. https://www.dropbox.com/s/65j6q5k3h8xnq0d/TASLAK%28%28Unsaved-305896342057530336%29%29.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can try the some absolutely free manual procedures given at- http://msofficerecovery.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-recover-corrupt-word-documents.html

Comment: I've found a file named as TASLAK((Unsaved-305896342057530336)).asd but I couldn't open.

Comment: If you can give an idea how to do it not just a link